# Webgl: pixel perfect tilemap rendering?

Tags: tilemap, webgl

The problem described below is a follow-up of [Seamless tilemap rendering (borderless adjacent images)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/74420/seamless-tilemap-rendering-borderless-adjacent-images).

I'm not sure to fully understand the rendering issue I have, so I'll try to describe as much as I can.

I had "seams" when rendering a tile map of tiles of 16px by 16px, more precisely I was seeing the following:

[image: seams]

I followed the recommendations describes in [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/75459/66608). It solved entirely the previous problem. However I now have the following rendering issue:

[image: blurry]

As you can see, everything is blurry.

I have also tried to do what is recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5879551/2246367), but it didn't change anything. I got the exact same output.

Last note, this is **not** always visible. When changing the position and scale of the camera, the rendering can end-up being correct. This is quite random though.

If you are interested in seeing some code, please have a look on the following links:

- [This](https://github.com/GreenPix/dilia/blob/map-ed/editor/components/map/editor-state.ts#L192-204) gives you a rough idea of the pipeline executed
- [This](https://github.com/GreenPix/dilia/blob/map-ed/editor/rendering/tiles.ts#L392-402) is where the texture coordinates are generated
- [This](https://github.com/GreenPix/dilia/blob/map-ed/editor/rendering/tiles.ts#L275-292) is where the buffers are instantiated
- [This](https://github.com/GreenPix/dilia/blob/map-ed/editor/rendering/shaders/tiles.fs) is the fragment shader
- [This](https://github.com/GreenPix/dilia/blob/map-ed/editor/rendering/shaders/tiles.vs) is the vertex shader

If you think you need more details, please feel free to ask me.